# Jupyter Notebook and Colab Keep Crashing From Running Random Forest Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, svm, random-forest

I currently have a dataset that has been encoded and it looks like this:

[image]

I then separated the independent and dependent variables as such, followed by separating the dataset into training and testing sets using sklearn packages.

```
X = df[['year', 'manufacturer', 'make', 'condition', 'cylinders', 'fuel', 'odometer', 'transmission', 'type']]
y = df['price']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(modX, y, test_size=0.25,random_state = 5)
```

Afterwards, I used a RandomForestClassifier to model the dataset:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import metrics

# Create a Gaussian Classifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, random_state=0, max_features = 'sqrt', n_jobs=4, verbose =1)

# train the model using the training sets y_pred = clif.predict(X_test)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# prediction on test set
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print("Accuracy:", accuracy)
```

However, everytime I run the code, my notebook crashes due to not having enough RAM. I've tried running the code on Colab (with GPU as well) and it crashes too. Is it due to the sheer amount of entries? I also tried using an SVM model to train the dataset, I ran the model overnight and nothing came about.

SVM Model:

```
from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='poly')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You are probably using too much RAM it seems. Look for example here for some reasons of memory usage: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32644/randomforest-reasons-for-memory-usage-consumption

Comment: I have tried changing the number of trees, depth, etc even to the smallest possible amount and it still crashes. Could it be the reason for it crashing is because the dataset is too big?

Answer (score 0):

Usually a solution to the problem is forcing it to build shallower trees by selecting any stopping/pruning hyperparameter (max depth, min leaves, etc.). Bear in mind that the memory usage grows linearly with the number of trees but exponentially with their depth :)

Comment: right, I'll keep that in mind as I keep trying to make it work. Thank you!