# RandomForestClassifier crashes on training

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, random-forest

I am using scikit.learn RandomForestClassifier to generate a binary classifier, whenever I try fitting the model instance with training dataset, the kernel crashes after 3 or 4 seconds, I read a stackoverflow answer (Link: [Jupyter Notebook and Colab Keep Crashing From Running Random Forest Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188852/jupyter-notebook-and-colab-keep-crashing-from-running-random-forest-model)) to use pruning methods, but they don't seem to work.

The code for the Classifier is as follows -

```
# implementing RF
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

# Instantiating rf model 
rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 10, random_state = 42, max_depth=10, max_leaf_nodes=10, max_features=None)

# Fitting the model
rf_model.fit(train_features, train_labels.ravel())
```

The shape of the training and testing dataset are as follows -

```
Training Features shape: (224553, 54)
Training Labels shape: (224553, 1)
Testing Features shape:(74852, 54)
Testing Labels shape: (74852, 1)
```

I have tried various methods but can't seem to fit the dataset, neither on my localmachine nor on Google collab, My machine stats are -

1. RAM 16gb
2. intel i7
3. Nvidia quadro 4gb graphics card

It would be great if you could help me with it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you try to put the value at max_depth=4 for start

Comment: Can you first try to train the random forest model with less max-depth and smaller dataset? What is the size of the largest training set which does not cause your notebook to crash?

Comment: @DataSciRookie even max_depth=4 crashses the kernel, it only increases the duration after which it crashes.

Comment: @AravindG.i will try reducing the training dataset, but it won't suffice my end result because i have to ensemble multiple algos, i feel it will reduce the accuracy of the target model